# MobileSDK IdentityProvider app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

We want to use the functionality of IdentityProvider described on this article:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/auth_identity_provider_ios.htm

However, this seems to be working on the Mobile SDK version 6 but not with version 7. Are there any updated documents about this?

The problem is when we try to make the code as the example on that site. Certain calls you can’t do it in the way that this tutorial shows you.

For example, One piece of code on the tutorial from this site (the one that you found) https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/auth_identity_provider_ios.htm:

```swift
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
    open url: URL, 
    options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
    {

    return UserAccountManager.sharedInstance().handleIDPAuthenticationResponse(url,

    options: options)

    return false;

    }
```

The line with "return UserAccountManager." code is not accessible anymore from the latest version of the SDKs (at least not in the same way)

Now, with the latest, we have to do it in this way (another piece of code I found in salesforce site in a different place https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates/blob/master/iOSIDPTemplate/Authenticator/AppDelegate.swift )

As you can see both piece of codes are doing the same thing but calling in different ways and different function names, so then it is really difficult to follow one tutorial if the calls are not the same anymore. There are even functions that we don’t find or have different arguments to pass to the function. That means that the tutorial is 6.0 or higher but not covering the latest.

It would be great to have a tutorial covering the latest SDK and showing how to do the IDP and IDP client (both) step by step with the libraries you need to include in the header, code, … Perhaps there is a place with the example, but we don’t find it…

Comment: We fixed this documentation code line in early August per your comment in the documentation. The doc now shows the updated Swift call:  return UserAccountManager.shared.handleIdentityProviderResponse(...

If you have specific questions about missing functions or renamed arguments, please send more details. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: Hi @RichardW we are just following the guide but we cant create a functional IDP client. maybe there is something missed in the guide? Salesforce can provide a example client project? 
thanks!

Comment: Hi Adrian, for a sample see https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates/tree/master/iOSIDPTemplate. You could use this template with `forceios createwithtemplate` (as described in the app's README.md) to create a basic IDP app, then port your own code and resources into it; or just browse its code. If you do use it, be sure that you're running forceios version 7.3.0 and CocoaPods version 1.7.5. Also, there's a recurring typo in the readme: "SalesforceMobileSDK-AuthTemplates" is obsolete and should be "SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates". Good luck, and keep us posted.